# How to call a function every n milliseconds in "real world" time exactly?

Tags: node.js, setinterval

If I understand correctly, `setInterval(() => console.log('hello world'), 1000)` will place the function to some queue of tasks to run. But if there are other tasks in-front of it, it won't run exactly at 1000 millisecond or every time.

In a single complex program, is it possible to also make calls to some function every n millisecond exactly in real world time with node.js ?

Comment: Possible, but very *bad* way: *block* in a `while` loop while calling `performance.now` or `Date`

Comment: If you have hard real time requirements, maybe JavaScript isn't the right tool.

Comment: Consider explaining your case. *But if there are other tasks in-front of it* - which tasks? If they are blocking, this obviously won't work. Otherwise it will.

Answer (score 3):

> But if there are other tasks in-front of it, it won't run exactly at 1000 millisecond or every time.

Your question is actually [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific, assuming the computer is running some (usual) operating system (like Windows, Android, Linux, MacOSX, etc...). I recommend reading [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to learn more.

In practice, your computer has many other [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) managed by its operating system. Some of them might be running. Your computer might be in a situation where it is loaded enough by *other* processes to the point of not being able to run your tasks or threads *exactly* every second. Read about [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)).

You might want to use some genuine [real-time operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system). But then, `node.js` probably won't run on it.

> How to call a function every n milliseconds in “real world” time exactly?

**You cannot do that reliably.** Because your `node.js` process (it is actually single threaded, at the system threads level, see [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) and [jfriend00's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53569352/841108)) might not get enough resources from your OS (so if other processes are loading your computer too much, `node.js` would be [starved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science)) and won't be able to progress like you want; be also aware of possible [priority inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion)).

On Linux, see also [shed(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html), [chrt(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chrt.1.html), [renice(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/renice.1.html)

Answer (score 3):

> If I understand correctly, setInterval(() => console.log('hello world'), 1000) will place the function to some queue of tasks to run. But if there are other tasks in-front of it, it won't run exactly at 1000 millisecond or every time.

That is correct.  It won't run exactly at the desired time if node.js happens to be busy doing something else when the timer is ready to run.  node.js will wait until it finishes it's other task before running the timer callback.  You can think of node.js as if it has a one-track mind (can only do one thing at a time) and timers don't ever interrupt existing tasks that are running.

> In a single complex program, is it possible to also make calls to some function every n millisecond exactly in real world time with node.js ?

No, it is not possible to do that in node.js.  node.js runs your Javascript as single-threaded, it's event driven and not-preemptive.  All of these mean that you cannot rely on code running at a precise real-world time.

What happens under the covers in node.js is that you set a timer for a specific time in the future.  That timer goes is registered with the node.js event loop so that each time it gets through the event loop, it will check if there are any pending timers.  But, it only gets through the event loop when other code that was running before the timer was ready to fire finishes running.  Here's the sequence of events:

- Run some code
- Set timer for some time in the future (say time X)
- Run some more code
- Nothing to do for awhile
- Run some more code (while this code is running, time X passes - the time for your timer to run)
- Previous block of code finishes running and control returns back to the node.js event loop at time X + n (some time after the timer X was supposed to fire).
- Event loop checks to see if there are any pending timers.  It finds a timer and calls its callback at time X + n.

So, the only way that your timer gets called at approximately time X is if node.js has nothing else to do at exactly time X.  If your program is ever doing anything else, you can't guarantee that your program will be free at exactly time X to run the timer exactly when you want it to run.   node.js is NOT a real-time system in any way.  single-threaded and non-pre-emptive mean that a timer may have to wait for node.js to finish some other things before it gets to run and thus there is no guarantee that the timer will run exactly on time.  Instead, it will run as not before time X when the interpreter is next free to return back to the event loop (done running whatever else might have been running at the time).  This could be close to time X or it could be a significant time after time X.

If you really need something to run precisely at a specific time, then you likely need a pre-emptive system (not node.js) that is much more real-time than node.js is.

---

You could create a "work-around" in node.js by firing up another node.js process (you could use the child_process module) and start a program in that other process that has nothing else to do except serve your timer and execute the code associated with that timer.  Then, at least you timer won't be pre-empted by some other Javascript task that might be running and will get to run pretty close to the desired time.  Keep in mind that even this work-around still isn't a true real-time system, but might serve some purposes.

Otherwise, you probably want to write this in a more real-time system language that has pre-emptive timers (probably even with thread priorities).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to make a **cron** which will run at every n seconds. If your program is complex and it may take more time then you can go with `async`.

```
npm install cron

var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
   console.log('You will see this message every second');

   callYourFunc();

}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

For more read this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

Comment: What if the n in the question is not an exact multiple of 1,000? You can’t use cron to run a job every 100 milliseconds, or every 5,500 milliseconds.

Comment: How exact is Cron? If you set it to fire every 1 second, does it really fire at *exactly* 1000 milliseconds? Or is it still a "best attempt"?

Comment: @MikeScott Yes I can understand that. It may put some load also on server continue. But I have just share option.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing As I mention in above comment, It is just another option of the issue. Well due to time duration gap is small, So it might be possible that some other way is more suitable solution for this. This is what I know about this. If I got some better option, I'll update in my answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could spawn a worker thread and block it while it’s waiting to do the work, in the way suggested by CertainPerformance in the comments. It may not be the most elegant way to do it but at least you can put the blocking logic aside so that it doesn’t affect the rest of the application.

Check out the example in the docs if you’re unfamiliar with the cluster module: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/cluster.html

Comment: The cluster module isn't going to solve this either.  While it lets you use multiple processes, it's still very possible for each clustered process to be busy at the exact time you want to run your task and then it will still be delayed.

Comment: Even if the clustered process is dedicated to only run the timer function?

Comment: It's not clear you understand what the cluster module does.  It splits incoming http requests among N separate processes giving you greater scale for processing incoming http requests (multiple processes all doing the same thing).  It doesn't allow you to create a new process that only does one thing.  For that, you would write a separate node.js app and use the child_process module to run it in a separate process (which is an option mentioned in my answer).

Comment: Right. I mixed the two of them together. Thanks for pointing that out.